# Extracting English-French cognates from a messy .txt glossary

Tags: strings, regex, r

After using an online tool to convert a PDF [glossary](https://pastebin.com/NUpvBNyY) of English-French cognates to a .txt file, I wanted to write a simple script to extract the cognate pairs and save them to a CSV. I could then import them to my flashcard software (Anki). The .txt file ended up being rather messy, and, as a novice programmer who's new to R, the only solution I found was rather crude.

Feedback on the slice/append calls in 1.) and the *hideous* indexing in 3.) would be particularly appreciated.

```
library(tidyverse) # dplyr
glossary <- as_tibble(read.delim("papers/frenchcognates.txt", encoding = "UTF-8", stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

## 1.) Extract cognates and language headings into a table. ##
cognates <- glossary %>% 
  # Select only the English-French half of the glossary.
  slice(1:1872) %>%
  # Extract the glossary entries (cognates) and headings ("English" or "French") 
  filter(str_detect(Glossary, "^[E-F]?[[:lower:]-]+[ \\(to\\)]*$")) %>% 
  # Language headings are misplaced for certain letters. Delete...# 
  slice(-543) %>% 
  slice(-613) %>% 
  slice(-723) 
#...then move for the while-loop later #
cognates <- append(cognates$Glossary,"French", after=551)  
cognates <- append(cognates,"French", after=622) # append() coerced the list to character vector 
cognates <- append(cognates,"French", after=733)

## 2.) Loop to separate words into two lists by language heading. ##
words <- vector("list", 2)
lang <- 1 # Using the language headers as a gate 
for (word in cognates) {
  if (word == "English") {
  lang <- 1 
  } else if (word == "French") { 
    lang <- 2
  } else {
    words[[lang]] <- c(words[[lang]], word) 
  }

## 3.) Combine lists into matrix/data frame, then save into CSV. ##
# Regex problem: months in English are capitalized, but aren't in French. 
words[[2]] <- words[[2]][!(words[[2]] %in% c("août", "décembre", "mars"))] 
words.mtx <- cbind(words[[1]], words[[2]])
# Convert to data frame (add colnames first)
colnames(words.mtx) <- c("english", "french") # add column names 
words.df <- as_tibble(words.mtx)
# Save to CSV
write_csv(words.df, "writing/cognates") # folder in my wd
```